# Prove that, for all integers $K$ and $L$, there is at least one pair of integers $(a, b)$ for which $K^2 + 3L^2 = a^2 + b^2 − ab$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, functions, contest-math

Prove that, for all integers $K$ and $L$, there is at least one pair of integers $(a, b)$ for which $$K^2 + 3L^2 = a^2 + b^2 − ab.$$

Able to find the reverse of this using even and odd cases but can't seem to crack this one? Could anyone help?

Comment: @WillJagy, indeed; https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=K%5E2+%2B+3L%5E2+%3D+a%5E2+%2B+b%5E2+%E2%88%92+ab

Comment: @lhf thanks, I did not think of searching   that way. I posted a Meta thing on contests, getting frustrated:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33425/how-likely-is-it-that-a-question-with-2021-is-from-a-current-contest